# Что значит данное выражение в PHP?

Tags: php

```
<?php echo("test\n"); ?>
```

Подскажите, что это значит?

Comment: Я тоже не понял. О чем вопрос?

Comment: Скрипт выводит строку `test` и переносит на новую строку

Answer (score 1):

Это escape знак. Применяется в программировании для обозначения невидимых/управляющих символов.

[Перечень](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-escapes-in-regular-expressions) escape символов

\n — это символ новой строки